# Bug in Grails / Spring Security when using user groups and roles - can't authenticate

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security

I think I have found a bug in Grails Spring Security 3.1.1, and latest Grails 3.2.6.

I have installed the Spring Security plugin.

From the command line console I did the following:

```
grails s2-quickstart org.softwood.security User Role --groupClassName=UserGroup
```

to create a user, role, and UserGroup table as I want to use the allocate roles to groups feature.  I then configured the domain classes, and added a few users in the bootstrap to test it out like this:

```
def loadSecurityUserAndRoles () {
    //plugin requires ROLE_ prefix see section 4.2/p18

    Role adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError:true)
    Role userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError:true)
    Role xtraRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_XTRA').save(failOnError:true)
    UserGroup adminGroup = new UserGroup (name:"GROUP_ADMIN").save(failOnError:true)
    UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup (name:"GROUP_USERS").save(failOnError:true)

    User userWill = new User(username: 'will', password: 'password').save(failOnError:true)
    User userMaz = new User(username: 'maz', password: 'password').save(failOnError:true)
    User userMeg = new User(username: 'meg', password: 'password').save(failOnError:true)

    //give adminGroup admin and user roles
    UserGroupToRole sgr = UserGroupToRole.create(adminGroup, adminRole)
    sgr = UserGroupToRole.create(adminGroup, userRole)

    sgr = UserGroupToRole.create(userGroup, userRole)

    assert UserGroupToRole.count() == 3

    def auth2 = adminGroup.getAuthorities()
    println "adminGroup authorities returned $auth2 "

    //assign test user to adminGroup, and maz+meg to user group, inherit all group roles
    UserToUserGroup su2g = UserToUserGroup.create (userWill, adminGroup, true)
    su2g = UserToUserGroup.create (userMaz, userGroup, true)
    su2g = UserToUserGroup.create (userMeg, userGroup, true)

    //assign individual 'xtra' role to user
    UserToRole sxtra = UserToRole.create(userWill, xtraRole, true)
    assert UserToRole.count() == 1

    def auth = userWill.getAuthorities()
    assert auth.collect{it.authority}.sort() == ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_XTRA']
    println "userWill authorities returned $auth "

    def mazAuth = userMaz.getAuthorities()
    def megAuth = userMeg.getAuthorities()
    println "user authorities returned maz: '$mazAuth', and meg: '$megAuth' "


    def groups = userWill.getUserGroups()
    assert groups.collect{it.name}.sort() == ['GROUP_ADMIN']

    assert UserGroup.count() == 2
    assert User.count() == 3
    assert Role.count() == 3
    assert UserToUserGroup.count() == 3
    assert UserGroupToRole.count() == 3
    assert UserToRole.count() == 1

}
```

This all seems to work as id expect and the basic asserts return the right numbers of roles for each user when I assert the `<userInst>.getAuthorities()`:

I then setup a controller `secureTest` with open action and secured one

```
class SecureTestController {

    def index() {
        render "hello Will you passed the permit_any"
    }

    @Secured ('ROLE_ADMIN')
    def secure () {
        render "hello Will you passed the ROLE_ADMIN"

    }
}
```

I run the app - it starts, I point the browser in `secureTest/index` - works fine as open url.

When I point the browser at secureTest/secure, it throws default login page.  I fill in will/password at it throws stacktrace and fails to login.

The key part of that trace is here I think:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: authorities for class: org.softwood.security.Role
Possible solutions: authority
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.propertyMissing(GormInstanceApi.groovy:55)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.propertyMissing(GormEntity.groovy:57)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$propertyMissing$9.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.softwood.security.Role.propertyMissing(Role.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:880)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1861)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3735)
    at org.softwood.security.Role.getProperty(Role.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:172)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService$_loadAuthorities_closure2.doCall(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
```

The method fails really here I think (GormUserDetailsService.groovy:92).

When you click that link the editor takes you to this in the plugin.

```
protected Collection<GrantedAuthority> loadAuthorities(user, String username, boolean loadRoles) {
    if (!loadRoles) {
        return []
    }

    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

    String authoritiesPropertyName = conf.userLookup.authoritiesPropertyName
    String authorityPropertyName = conf.authority.nameField

    boolean useGroups = conf.useRoleGroups
    String authorityGroupPropertyName = conf.authority.groupAuthorityNameField

    Collection<?> userAuthorities = user."$authoritiesPropertyName"
    def authorities

    if (useGroups) {
        if (authorityGroupPropertyName) {
            authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
        }
        else {
            log.warn 'Attempted to use group authorities, but the authority name field for the group class has not been defined.'
        }
    }
    else {
        authorities = userAuthorities.collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
    }
    authorities ?: [NO_ROLE]
}
```

The key part here is this call sequence:

```
    if (useGroups) {
        if (authorityGroupPropertyName) {
            authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
        }
```

useGroups is true. I have a authorityGroupPropertyName that was set in application.groovy file by quick install script:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.groupAuthorityNameField = 'authorities'
```

so this code line above calls:

```
userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique()
```

this returns a hashSet of `role.authority` names as string and the flatten/unique just makes sure there are no nested structure and strings are unique. So far so good.

The last bit is the bug I think.

```
<hashSet of role Names>.collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
```

In this bit the collect method is called on the set of strings but the string passed to 'SimpleGrantedAuthority' should just be the string.  instead its calling

```
it."$authorityPropertyName"
```

where it is a string and has no such property.

The key bits set up in application.groovy are:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'org.softwood.security.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authoritiesPropertyName = 'authorities'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'org.softwood.security.UserToUserGroup'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'org.softwood.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.groupAuthorityNameField = 'authorities' //'authority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRoleGroups = true
```

As you can see I tried to change authorities to 'authority' as that's the property name in the role class.  That fails with missing property message also.

I think this is a bug and the code should just have passed 'it':

```
.collect {new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it)}
```

to generate the hashSet of `<SimpleGrantedAuthority>` types.

Has any one else had this problem with Spring Security?  I can't believe I'm the first to have fallen over it, or maybe no one is trying to use groups?

Comment: The `getAuthorities` method has been generated by the plugin in your User.groovy class  for example 

I have a slightly different setup, you can tweak these to work differently and it maybe that you need to fine tune this bit.


 Set<RoleGroup> getAuthorities() {
  UserRoleGroup.findAllByUser(this)*.roleGroup
 }

Comment: vahid - i did a tweak on the classes - but tested the assertions and responses - i've allowed for roles inherited via the userGroup - and individual role assignments - i have the code here on github so feel to get a clone https://github.com/woodmawa/coffeeShopApp.  What i understand user.getAuthorities() to do is return a Set of Roles (Authorities) and i've walked the code and it does just that.  but the code i hilighted will break

Comment: I may have misunderstood what was to happen - but if you look at the code secition for just user/role (no groups ) , `authorities = userAuthorities.collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }`  you'll see its working on a set<Role> in which case the `it."$authorityPropertyName"` works fine.  but it cant work in the group case `authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }` because here there are two collects.  i'll have another check tomorrow

Comment: Sorry I haven't had the time to delve into your issue, in all honesty got plenty of my own issues just like to help in little ways if possible. Anyhow that line you are pointing out https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/userdetails/GormUserDetailsService.groovy#L99 is in current version of plugin so unsure if it is causing your issue

Comment: thanks vahid - i think i need to report it, i'm as close as i can be saying this cant work as the team intended.  just not sure of how i code round it without doing a pull on the project and chaging the code - which i'm nervous of doing

Comment: unsure it is a bug, I have a working version of group roles and a process to add so will post that as answer and hopefully from it you can change your code/make yours work.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code out of the GormUserDetailsService into my bootstrap so I could expand expand/play in my own file space.

I modified the if block and expanded in out like this:

```
    if (useGroups) {
            if (authorityGroupPropertyName) {
                //userAuthorities returns Set<Role>
                println """ debug
authoritiesPropertyName = $authoritiesPropertyName
authorityPropertyName = $authorityPropertyName
authorityGroupPropertyName = $authorityGroupPropertyName
userAuthorities returns $userAuthorities of type ${userAuthorities.getClass()}

"""
                 def roles = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique()

                authorities = roles.collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
```

my debug string shows this on the console

```
 debug
authoritiesPropertyName = authorities
authorityPropertyName = authority
authorityGroupPropertyName = authority
userAuthorities returns [Role(authority:ROLE_XTRA), Role(authority:ROLE_USER), Role(authority:ROLE_ADMIN)] of type class java.util.HashSet
```

The first result returned into variable 'roles' is an ArrayList of String (each of the role.authority name instances.  with correct values for this user as in earlier bootstrap setup for userWill.

The next of code now fails as I have an ArrayList of string, and it tries to access a property:

```
 authorities = roles.collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
```

which fails with:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: authority for class: java.lang.String
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at coffeeshopapp.BootStrap$_loadSecurityUserAndRoles_closure6.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at coffeeshopapp.BootStrap.loadSecurityUserAndRoles(BootStrap.groovy:115)
```

Whichever way I cut this, this single line in the original source just doesn't work. Original line reads again:

```
        authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
```

If it had read instead like this - the code would work:

```
        authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it) }
```

Surely the code in the v3.1.1 plugin can't work?

Answer (score 0):

I have configured users role and role group too, this is how mine is working:

In user class:

```
   Set<RoleGroup> getAuthorities() {
        UserRoleGroup.findAllByUser(this)*.roleGroup
    }
   //not used
   // Set<RoleGroup> getAuthoritiesNames() {
   //     UserRoleGroup.findAllByUser(this)*.roleGroup?.name
   // }

    Set<Role> getAuthority() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }
```

In RoleGroup.groovy I have: (think I changed these unsure)

```
Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        RoleGroupRole.findAllByRoleGroup(this)*.role
    }
    def getAuthority() {
        RoleGroupRole.withTransaction {
            RoleGroupRole.findAllByRoleGroup(this)*.role.authority[0]
        }
    }
```

In my bootstrap something like this creates default admin account bound to role and role group:

```
private void addAdminUser(String username) {
        User adminUser = User.findByUsername(username)
        if (!adminUser) {

            User.withTransaction {
                adminUser = new User(username: username, password: 'PASSWORD'
                )
                adminUser.save(flush: true)
            }
        }
        def adminRole
        Role.withTransaction {
            adminRole= Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
            if (!adminRole) {
                adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
                UserRole.create adminUser, adminRole,true
            }
        }
        def adminRoleGroup
        RoleGroup.withTransaction {
            adminRoleGroup = RoleGroup.findByName('ADMINS')
            if (!adminRoleGroup) {
                adminRoleGroup = new RoleGroup(name: 'ADMINS').save(flush: true)
            }
        }
        UserRoleGroup.withTransaction {
            def adminRoleGroupRole = RoleGroupRole.findByRole(adminRole)
            if (!adminRoleGroupRole) {
                adminRoleGroupRole = new RoleGroupRole(role: adminRole, roleGroup: adminRoleGroup).save(flush: true)
                new UserRoleGroup(user: adminUser, roleGroup: adminRoleGroup).save(flush: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've unpeeled the onion and found the issue.

Step 1. I went back to beginning and created a new project from scratch and added the grails-security plugin on empty project.  From Grails console used this as per oneline guide `grails s2-quickstart org.softwood User Role --groupClassName=RoleGroup`.

This worked, so I compared what it had generated with what I'd got myself into and I think I understand where the problem for me was.

My role class was the same as empty test one - no difference.

Then I got to the User class, and somehow I'd got the getAuthorities() returning `Set<Role>` (this seemed sensible as the getAuthorites() in my UserGroup (aka RoleGroup in fresh start) returns `Set<Role>`.  And basic User/Role returns `Set<Role>`.

If you generate a project with just User and Role, then User.getAuthorities() returns `set<Role>`.  But when using a group the template is changed and `Set<UserGroup>` was being returned.

That difference is crucial, as the code that adjusts its de-referencing strategy is in code in  GormUserDetailsService.loadAuthorities() where it can't be seen - see my 'tweaked version I'd been trying to fix.

```
    if (useGroups) {
        if (authorityGroupPropertyName) {
            //authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
            //ww edit to stop gpf..  userAuthorities is Set<Role>, so first collect gets the names and produces ArrayList of string
            //second collect builds the authorities as Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority>
            authorities = userAuthorities.collect { it."$authorityGroupPropertyName" }.flatten().unique().collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it) }
        }
        else {
            log.warn 'Attempted to use group authorities, but the authority name field for the group class has not been defined.'
        }
    }
    else {
        authorities = userAuthorities.collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it."$authorityPropertyName") }
    }
```

The problem with this is that the `def authorities` variable changes type depending on whether using user/role or user/group/role model.

I fell bang into the middle of this; I was trying to use groups (default allocation model) but permit individual Role assignments (individual granted Roles, as override facility).

When I read the `User.authorities` property - I assumed this would return the Roles it was linked with (via groups, and via my individual assignment override) (like in single user/role model).  I'd sorted this out in my domain class code like this in class user.

```
Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    //orig UserUserGroupBroken.findAllByUser(this)*.userGroup

    Set<Role> individualRoles = UserToRole.findAllByUser(this)*.role
    Set<UserGroup> groups = UserToUserGroup.findAllByUser(this)*.group
    Set<Role> groupRoles = groups.collect{it.getAuthorities() }
    Set<Role> aggregateRoles = new HashSet()
    aggregateRoles.addAll (groupRoles.flatten())
    aggregateRoles.addAll (individualRoles.flatten())
    aggregateRoles
}
```

So that all seemed sensible and did what I wanted (my tests showed the the correct Roles assigned via the superposition). However the GormUserDetailsService wasn't expecting that and broke as if useGroups is true it de-references two sets to get a `Set<Role>`, and use that to build the SimpleGrantedAuthority Set from.

The upshot of this is my purpose is defeated: it's too far a deviation from the assumed model.

I'll make it as a suggestion on the Git site, as it would just be so much cleaner and less opaque, and I think you intuitively assume that the `authorities` property on users will give you a `Set<Role>`.

For now just going to have to stick with just the basic user/group/role model and live with that.