# Cannot run grails plugin after creation. Get ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication Application startup failed

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I am having hard time to figure out why Grails fails to run a plugin I created. This is my environment:

- Grails Version: 3.2.6
- Groovy Version: 2.4.7
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_91

And these are my steps:

1. I created the plugin with:

   ```
   grails create-plugin bioprofile
   ```
2. I add the Spring Security core plugin, by adding this line to `build.gradle`:

   ```
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
   ```
3. I ran the `s2-quickstart` command to set `User`, `Role` and `UserRole`:

   ```
   grails s2-quickstart cscie56.ps5 User Role
   ```
4. I modified the `User` domain class to include some new fields
5. Created a few other domain classes

   ```
   grails create-domain-class cscie56.ps5.BlogEntry
   grails create-domain-class cscie56.ps5.Comment
   ```
6. I generated the controllers, etc...

   ```
   grails generate-all BlogEntry
   grails generate-all User
   grails generate-all Role
   grails generate-all UserRole
   ```
7. I added the following initialization in the `BootStrap.groovy` file:

   ```
   package bioprofile

   import cscie56.ps5.Role
   import cscie56.ps5.User
   import cscie56.ps5.UserRole

   class BootStrap {

       def init = { servletContext ->
           environments {
               development {
                   setupData()
                   setupUsersAndRoles()
                   println "Developement execution"
               }
               test {
                   setupData()
                   setupUsersAndRoles()
                   println "Test execution"
               }
               production {
                   // do nothing
                   println "Production execution"
               }
           }
       }

       def destroy = {
       }

       def setupUsersAndRoles() {
           User admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'password')
           admin.save(flush: true)
           User user = new User(username: 'user', password: 'user')
           user.save(flsuh:true)

           Role adminRole = new Role(authority: Role.ROLE_ADMIN)
           adminRole.save(flush:true)

           Role userRole = new Role(authority: Role.ROLE_USER)
           userRole.save(flush:true)

           UserRole.create(admin, adminRole)
           UserRole.create(admin, userRole)
           UserRole.create(user, userRole)
       }

       def setupData() {

       }
   }
   ```

When I run the app with `grails run-app` I get this tedious error:

```
Running application...
objc[84720]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

2017-04-06 06:20:06.032 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [cscie56.ps5.User] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.stateException(GormEnhancer.groovy:387)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findInstanceApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:273)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findInstanceApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:270)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.currentGormInstanceApi(GormEntity.groovy:1326)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at cscie56.ps5.User.save(User.groovy)
    at cscie56.ps5.User.save(User.groovy)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at bioprofile.BootStrap.setupUsersAndRoles(BootStrap.groovy:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at bioprofile.BootStrap$_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:13)
    at bioprofile.BootStrap$_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(BootStrap.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at bioprofile.BootStrap$_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.call(BootStrap.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
    at bioprofile.BootStrap$_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.call(BootStrap.groovy)
    at grails.util.Environment$EnvironmentBlockEvaluator.execute(Environment.java:529)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:510)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:485)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:256)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at bioprofile.Application.main(Application.groovy:10)
```

I tried to run

```
grails clean
grails clean --refresh-dependencies
grails compile
```

but same result.

Anyone has encountered this issue or have an idea what the root cause is?

Comment: The issues (I still don't understand the root cause) seems to be related to the following instruction:

admin.save(flush: true)
adminRole.save(flush:true)
userRole.save(flush:true)

... so something is not maybe properly initialized to allow persistance to happen ?

Comment: .withTransaction {

Comment: @vahid Can you give more details ?

Comment: This is a repeated topic did you do any searches for that term. Cos if you did pretty sure plenty of results would have been returned.  Services in grails are auto transactional any other place on grails 3 and you need to wrap transaction around it.

Comment: Similar topics indicated missing hibernate configuration, but as far as I can see the generated configuration boilerplate looks fine in my case for hibernate 5. These are domain classes no services. Can you point me out to a proper example where the .withTransaction should be use and what it should actually wrap ?

Comment: I would highly recommend trying it on a lower version of grails just to satisfy it is not related to the latest release so does the same thing work under 3.1.10 as an example ? I would also recommend you look at another example i gave here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460249/bug-in-grails-spring-security-when-using-user-groups-and-roles-cant-authentic/42468968#42468968 on this you will see .withTransaction around the calls. I mean have you even tried my suggestion ?

Comment: I sorted out. It seemed to be an issue with hibernate dependencies. The generated dependencies had one reference to hibernate5. I changed to hibernate4, adding these 3 references: compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.10.Final"
This made it work. Now I have a new problem, the application starts and I can open the console to browse database, but no user data are created. I added the .withTrasnaction stuff you mentioned (I found an example - although it seems to be an hack). Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me, if someone else is going to have the same problem.
It seems like it was an hibernate dependencies issue. Not obvious, and most likely a subtle bug of whatever is generating the boilerplate stuff across the several files (never been a big fan of "I'll do it all for you" frameworks).
In my specific case (and this might be specific to my environment) by replacing the generated hibernate5 dependencies with hibernate4 in the build.gradle file, the error above went away. This is what I have now (removed the hibernate5 stuff):

```
classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.10"

compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.10.Final"
```

The .withTransaction { hack did not seem to have any effect in solving this problem.